# Regex with two optional capturing groups

Tags: regex

I don't know what is wrong with my regex : I try to clean all css styles excepted height / width (if they exist).

```
style=".*(height: *\d*px|em|%)?.*(width: *\d*px|em|%)?.*"
```

Thank for your help

Comment: Which lang are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to just scan out all the matches from your string, then replace the string with the concatenated matches. The pattern for a valid property is something like:

```
/(\b(?:height|width):\s*\d+(?:px|em|%))/i
```

So, for example, in Ruby, I'd do something like:

```
str = "foo: 123;  width: 10%; height: 40px"
str.scan(/(\b(?:height|width):\s*\d+(?:px|em|%))/).flatten.join("; ")
# => "width: 40px; height: 10%"
```

Comment: Thanks. I dont know Ruby, but I tried this in javascript with match function. The problem is that only the last captured group is recorded. So for example if there is a height attribute and then a width, the height will be forgotten.

Comment: You need to add the "global" flag to get all matches. `"foo: 123;  width: 10%; height: 40px".match(/(\b(?:height|width):\s*\d+(?:px|em|%))/g)` => `["width: 10%", "height: 40px"]`

Comment: Yes, but in my case I have an unknown number of [style="..."], so I can't just match 'height' and 'width' attributes in all the text.

Comment: Well, you didn't really specify that in your question. You're probably going to want an actual XML parser to extract the style attributes, which you can then sanitize with your regexps or whatever.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit about my context. I need the regexp to begin with `style="...` so that I'm sure I sanitize each style attribute, and only style attribute. If the sample I proposed was right, I could then have made a substitution with `style="$1;$2"`